# isnull() function is not identifying missing values in my data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-cleaning

I am using df[''].isnull() on a data frame I am currently using pulled from a CSV. It is practice data that has lots of missing values and errors intentionally, however, pandas cannot identify the missing values in the DOB column, having verified there are missing values based on opening the CSV and seeing the empty cells under the DOB column.

```
df['DOB'].isnull().sum()
Output: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first convert column to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors='coerce'` for parse non datetime-like to `NaT` for misisng values and then count:

```
df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'], errors='coerce')

out = df['DOB'].isnull().sum()
```

Comment: Hmm 'out' is still returning 0, could this be an issue with my dataset?

Comment: @Nish - yes, is possible add some sample data rows  with missing values?

Comment: So I created a random column and deleted some observations within it, isnull() seems to be working fine on there, it reported a correct quantity

Comment: @Nish - So it means no missing values in real data?

Comment: It recognizes the missing data that I just created, but not recognizing the missing data in the dataset or the DOB column at least

Comment: @Nish - How looks missing data in dataset ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223577/discussion-between-jezrael-and-nish).